# Result of `free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00005643b9765c80` despite correct debug outputs

Tags: c++, pointers

I am getting a result of `free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00005643b9765c80` despite having correct debug outputs.

For context, I was implementing a suffix tree in a very brute approach. The code for the following is given below:

```cpp
struct SUFFIX_TREE {
    /*
    * connects node src and nxt
    * maps from idx to idx + len - 1
    */
    struct EDGE {
        int src, nxt;
        int idx, len;
        EDGE() {
            src = nxt = idx = len = -1;        
        }
        EDGE(int src, int nxt, int idx, int len): src(src), nxt(nxt), idx(idx), len(len) {}
        void print() {
            cout << "EDGE: \n";
            cout << "src: " << src << " nxt: " << nxt << "\n";
            cout << "l: " << idx << " r: " << idx + len - 1 << "\n"; 
        }
    };

    /*
    * id is the index of a node in nodes
    * map of int to EDGE is mapping of the actual value of starting index
    * leafSuf denotes suffix value
    */
    struct NODE {
        int id;
        int leafSuf;
        map<int, EDGE*> adj;
        NODE(int id) id:(id) {
            leafSuf = -1;
            adj = map<int, EDGE*>();
        }
        void print() {
            cout << "NODE: " << id << "\n";
            cout << "leafSuf: " << leafSuf << "\n";
            for (auto &it: adj) {
                cout << "rep: " << it.first << "\n";
                it.second->print();
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }
    };

    /* ========================== */

    const int TERM = 1e9;
    int n;
    vector<int> a;
    vector<NODE> nodes;

    /* ========================== */

    void reset() {
        nodes.clear();
        a.clear();
    }

    /*
    * append TERM at end
    */
    void init(vector<int> &A) {
        a = vector<int>(A);
        a.push_back(TERM);
        n = a.size();        
        form();
    }
    
    /*
    * Suffix tree with O(n^2) construction
    */
    void form() {
        // root of suffix tree
        nodes.push_back({0});
        for (int suf = 0; suf < n; ++ suf) {
            int cur = suf;
            int at = 0;
            while (1) {               
                if (nodes[at].adj.find(a[cur]) != nodes[at].adj.end()) { // insert here
                    EDGE* e = nodes[at].adj[a[cur]];
                    int lo = e->idx;
                    int hi = lo + e->len - 1;
                    int ptr = lo;

                    int ncur = cur;
                    while (ncur < n && ptr <= hi && a[ptr] == a[ncur]) {
                        ptr ++; ncur ++;
                    }
                    assert(ncur != n);

                    if (ptr > hi) { // there is still matching left, go to next node
                        at = e->nxt;
                        cur = ncur;
                    } else { // need to split edge
                        NODE nNode(nodes.size());
                        nodes.push_back(nNode);

                        // create new edge
                        EDGE* ne = new EDGE(at, nNode.id, lo, ptr - lo);

                        // edge e
                        e->src = nNode.id;
                        e->idx = ptr;
                        e->len = hi - ptr + 1;

                        // adjust nNode
                        nNode.adj[a[ptr]] = e;

                        // adjust current node
                        nodes[at].adj[a[cur]] = ne;

                        // create a new leaf for remaining of current suffix
                        NODE nLeaf(nodes.size());
                        nLeaf.leafSuf = suf;
                        nodes.push_back(nLeaf);

                        // create a new edge for connecting to new leaf
                        EDGE* nle = new EDGE(nNode.id, nLeaf.id, ncur, n - ncur);


                        // adjust nNode
                        nNode.adj[a[ncur]] = nle;

                        break;
                    }               
                } else { // add a new edge
                    NODE nLeaf(nodes.size());
                    nLeaf.leafSuf = suf;

                    EDGE* ne = new EDGE(at, nLeaf.id, cur, n - cur);
                    nodes[at].adj[a[cur]] = ne;

                    nodes.push_back(nLeaf);
                    break;
                }
            }
            print(suf);
        }
    }

    /*
    * Prints the suffix tree
    */
    void print(int ex) {
        cout << "\n"; 
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); ++ i)
            nodes[i].print();
        cout << "\n"; 
    }
};
```

I have had very little experience of managing struct pointers and especially moving their references around. I believe the section `need to split edge` might contain some erroneous code. But on debugging after each `EDGE` creation, reference passing & at the end of each iteration, I found every node to be intact and correct with edges correctly placed, yet somehow at the end of the main loop in `form` method, I am getting an error of `free(): invalid pointer`.

Any and all help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Such errors typically happens when you write out of bounds of your allocated memory.

Comment: But on debugging, every edge and node I am creating seems to be correctly placed. If I were to write out of bounds, wouldn't I be not able to see what I have written?

Comment: Not if you also *read* from out of bounds, then it might seem to work.

Comment: Use a memory debugger like [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org) to help you find problems like this. Or build with address-sanitizer.

Comment: Sure I will take a look at this! Thanks!

Comment: The code at `adjust nNode` makes the change to the local `nNode` variable, not the node stored in `nodes`. You never check to see if `at` is out of bounds; is it possible that `at = e->nxt` assigns an index that is too large??